# Good Open Source SNMP agent for an embedded device

Tags: open-source, snmp

we are trying to assess some good open source snmp agents to embedded on a device. Any recommendations which are time tested and robust? -Sathia

Comment: Which operating system you use?

Answer (score 5):

[NET-SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net) is a SNMP agent whose storage footprint can be reduced to less than 0.5 MB.

There is also a net-snmp package available for [openembedded](http://www.openembedded.org).